# How can I make the for work in this function?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

could you help me with this problem? damned for! :p

```
def exchange(x):
    r = requests.get(URL1 + x + URL2)
    js = r.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js, orient="index").transpose()
    return df
```

if capture data with next code, after individual append() i have expected answer:

```
c = exchange("tiendacrypto")
d = exchange("belo")
c.append(d)
```

but, i don't find the error in the for:

```
a = []
for i in exchanges:
    print(exchange(i))
    a = exchange(i)
    a.append(a)
```

Comment: What is ``?

Comment: some funny unicode stuff here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the reassignment of the a value on line 2 in the for loop.

You need to use a different variable name.

```
 = []
   :
    (())
    x = ()
    .(x)
```

Notice how we dont now change a in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `a` twice.

```
 = []
   :
    (())
     = () # Here is overwritten!
    .()#
```

```
results = []
   :
    df = ()
    ((df))
    results.(df)
```